# How to generate a JWT with Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, entity-framework-core

Hello i'm confused when creating a token with Net Core, i have followed a guide and is not working when i execute in Postman the Post request.

See, i have my database with ef core migrations, and my User class have UserName and Password {get;set;}.

Then i created an AuthController that contains this:

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly HacsysContext _context;
    public AuthController(IConfiguration configuration, HacsysContext context) {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("token")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Personal personal)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userId = GetUserIdFromCredentials(personal);
            if (userId == -1)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, personal.CorreoE),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken
            (
                issuer: _configuration["Issuer"],
                audience: _configuration["Audience"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10),
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["SigningKey"])),
                     SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

            return Ok(new { token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }

    private int GetUserIdFromCredentials(Personal personal)
    {
        var userId = -1;

        var email = personal.CorreoE;
        var password = personal.Contrasena;
        if (personal.CorreoE.Equals(email)) 
            {
                userId = 1;
            }



        return userId;


    }
}
```

Basically, when i compare in GetUserIdFromCredentials if the email is equals to peronal.CorreoE returns always True, even if in Postman i send a POST whith only one letter or diferent Email or different Email that is not in my database.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting userId 1 everytime because you are first setting the email value to the value 
of `personal.CorreoE` and then comparing if the `email` value is equal to `personal.CorreoE`.. This will allways be true and therefore return 1.

But what you should do is make a query on the Personal entity in the dbContext to find a person with that email and return userId of the found entity

```
private int GetUserIdFromCredentials(Personal personal)
{
    var email = personal.CorreoE;
    var password = personal.Contrasena;

    //make a query on the db context
    var dbPerson = _context.Personal.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Email == email);

    if(dbPerson == null)
        return -1;

    return dbPerson.Id;
}
```